# Akka.net asynchronous method handling

Tags: asp.net, akka.net

I have a web api REST service exposed in IIS 7.0. I have a POST method which takes collection of request object, we
need to concurrently submit each request object to backend data source, aggregate and return the result.
There can be more than 100 request objects and the response size is around 1 MB. We want the response to be 
back to the channels in 3 secs, each backend call (web service call to another data source) takes less than 500 ms approx

My question is -

1. How can we achieve this?
2. can we achieve this through Akka.net what are the options?

Answer (score 0):

Akka.net is an actor framework.  Actors are designed to process one message at a time and to isolate their state so that there are no shared resources between actors.  Actors are not necessarily a framework for concurrency, though there are ways to model concurrent operations with actors.  For example, you could have an actor serve as a router with a pool of actors that each insert one record into the underlying repository.  However, this would not attempt to insert all requests concurrently, because the router pool will have a maximum size, so that will be the limit on concurrent inserts.

A simple way to achieve your desired behavior without Akka.net might be to use [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/parallel-linq-plinq) to insert your requests objects into the database concurrently.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, i have a doubt here.As per my knowledge PLINQ works best for CPU bound operation, in my case I have extensive I/O operations. How can i parallelise I/O operations and at the same time achieve good perfromance

Comment: Is your IO blocking or `async`?  If it's blocking, I'd try PLINQ.  If it's `async`, you could try just using a regular `Select` and using `Task.WhenAll`.  Either way, I think you should experiment with profiling your code to see if a simple solution will work before redesigning the application with something like the actor model.